# cant create table in laravel 5.5 using migration because of foreign key fail

Tags: mysql, laravel

I get the following error when I run the migration command

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test`.`#sql-644_119` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint i
>     s incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `show_packages` add constraint `show_packages_package_id_foreign` foreign
>     key (`package_id`) references `rent_package_no` (`id`))

these are my table
[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please show the migration.

Comment: Schema::create('show_packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('pack_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('cat_id')->unsigned(); 
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('pack_id')->references('id')->on('rent_package_no');
            $table->foreign('cat_id')->references('id')->on('rent_lend_categories');
        });

Comment: It's a migration for `pack_id` and not for `package_id`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Thanks...problem solved ...all this happened because of order of migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order of your migrations. If your migrate command is trying to make the `rent_package_no` table before the `show_packages` table this will occur with MySQL. It seems to go in order of date, oldest to newest. In other words, the cat_id on the the table it is trying to reference should exist.

Comment: thanks.. so how can I migrate rent_package_no table first...because i create show_package migration first. sorry, I'm new.

Comment: @akshay-dighe For example, change the file name. Migration files are sorted by name

Comment: Thanks...problem solved ...all this happened because of order of migration

Comment: @akshay-dighe You are wellcome). If i help you, please, chek my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Migration order matter's here
ensure that your foreign tables(rent_package_no & rent_lend_categories) is created before running this migration

Try using the below code:

```
Schema::create('show_packages', function(Blueprint $table) { 
    $table - > increments('id');
    $table - > integer('pack_id') - > unsigned();
    $table - > integer('cat_id') - > unsigned();
    $table - > timestamps();
    $table - > foreign('pack_id') - > references('id') - > on('rent_package_no')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table - > foreign('cat_id') - > references('id') - > on('rent_lend_categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 
});
```

Comment: The order of migration file matters due to which you are facing this issue probably. Move your foreign table migration file i.e (rent_package_no and rent_lend_categories) on top of this migration file.

Comment: Thanks...problem solved ...all this happened because of order of migration